# Environment variables over ssh block in shell script

Tags: shell-script, ssh, quoting, here-document

I have the following function :

```
GetHostName () {
NODE01_CHECK=`cat /etc/hosts | grep -w "node01" | awk '{print $1}'`
NODE02_CHECK=`cat /etc/hosts | grep -w "node02" | awk '{print $1}'`

IS_NODE1=`ifconfig -a | grep -w $NODE01_CHECK`
IS_NODE2=`ifconfig -a | grep -w $NODE02_CHECK`

if [[ ! -z $IS_NODE1 ]]; then
    echo "This is NODE 1"
fi

if [[ ! -z $IS_NODE2 ]]; then
    echo "This is Node 2"
fi

}
```

This script will identify if a certain ip is configured on one of the two nodes belonging to a cluster. This works fine locally, but I need to run it remotely from a server that only knows of the VIP of the cluster. The goal is to transfer some files to both nodes.

So when I run :

```
scp -r /tmp/files CLUST_VIP 
ssh CLUST_VIP <<EOF

        NODE01_CHECK=`cat /etc/hosts | grep -w "node01" | awk '{print $1}'`
        NODE02_CHECK=`cat /etc/hosts | grep -w "node02" | awk '{print $1}'`

        IS_NODE1=`ifconfig -a | grep -w $NODE01_CHECK`
        IS_NODE2=`ifconfig -a | grep -w $NODE02_CHECK`

        if [[ ! -z $IS_NODE1 ]]; then
               scp -r /tmp/files node02
        fi

        if [[ ! -z $IS_NODE2 ]]; then
               scp -r /tmp/files node01
        fi

  EOF
```

However, now while running the same commands in a ssh block, I get the following messages :

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

I have also tried using `ssh -t` and that removed the above errors regarding `grep`, but the environment variables do not seem to work.

Is there a way to use environment variables over a ssh block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man bash`:

> The format of here-documents is:

```
          <<[-]word
                  here-document
          delimiter
```

> No  parameter  and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>          expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on *word*.  If any  characters  in *word* are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal
>          on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  **If *word*
>          is  unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
>          expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the  character  sequence  \<newline>  is  ignored, and \ must be used to quote the
>          characters \, $, and `**.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables and subshells are being executed prior to sending it over SSH.  You can see that if you replace your `ssh` command with `cat`.  You could quote `EOF` to prevent that expansion (as highlighted in AlexP's answer), or, since you're already doing an `scp` right above that step you could just put this in a script and execute it on the other side.

Since you're using bash-isms in it you might want to consider that anyway just in case this is ever executed by someone who doesn't use `bash` as their shell.

Also, `grep` can process files, so you don't need to `cat` a file into it, and you're missing a target on your `IS_NODE2` block `scp` command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think a secondary script on the target is the way to go in this case. Just tesded it and it works.